# vcprompt not setting modified and uncommitted in prompt

Tags: git, svn, bash, prompt

Using iTerm2 and-or Terminal on OSX - Ive got the lastest version of vcprompt installed and working to a point. I cant seem to get the format to reflect modified (+) and uncommitted (?) in my prompt. 
i.e. `$user: path [git:branch +?]`.

In .bash_login

`print_before_prompt (){

   printf "\e[0;35m%s: \e[0;36m%s \e[0;33m%s\e[0m \n" "$USER" "$PWD" "$(vcprompt -f %n:%b %u%m)"
}`

GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=true
GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES=true

PROMPT_COMMAND=print_before_prompt

PS1="→ "
PS2=" > "

`Also added bash.showDirtyState true` in --global git config file
but I dont get the indicators as expected: actually all it does is remove the [ ] from around [git:branch]. $user: path git:branch

I know this is pretty fringe but help on this would be great --

Comment: 5 years later... I'll add my 2 cents to this post:  I notice that the format above omits the [ ] which you're referring to -- so I believe you would want to use something like `-f [%n:%b%u%m]` (and as I've noted, spaces within the format string seem to break the parser, so I was only able to use non-whitespace formatting)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to specify which vcprompt you're talking about -- I'm the author of the original C version (https://bitbucket.org/gward/vcprompt), but I know of at least two re-implementations which have "borrowed" the name vcprompt. Anyways, I can only answer for my version.

I don't think this feature was implemented for git when you posted your question originally, which would explain why it didn't work back then.

It should be working fine in the latest version of vcprompt (1.1 as I write this, 1.2 coming shortly). I believe vcprompt 1.1 is packaged by homebrew for OS X, so it should be easy to install/upgrade.